# Tan Tan Radius in AutoCAD doesn't put circle on right side

Tags: autocad

I've been struggling to this for some time now and can't really find the answer on the web, but: sometimes when I want to set circle inside of an angle, it just throws it out on the wrong side. Like on the photo below: I wanted to insert circle between two lines and trim it (so it would look like red arc at the end), where I choose 2 lines (TTR command) where the green stars are, but the circle got dropped on the other side.

What's going wrong here, what's the matter?
I had my mouse (while entering radius) on the right side of the vertical line.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll find that selecting your two tan lines in the opposite order will get it on the correct side. Also you may want to consider the fillet command as a shortcut, although it doesn't work with all object types.

Comment: About first part of the comment: thank you, it might help.
About second part: I thought fillet is for 3D only.

Comment: Fillet works in 2d as well, but there are limitations on the types of objects. I think it's mainly splines that it won't do.

Comment: https://mgfx.co.za/blog/building-architectural-design/autocad-circle-by-tan-tan-radius/
This link has a helpful video, and if you make the circles first it makes everything possible.

Comment: Fillet with radius set to 0 is a tip/trick to bring two lines together at a corner as it is essentially performing extend and trim functions as required simultaneously

Comment: @Ethan48, I just tested filleting a 2D spline with a line using a radius and it worked. (AutoCAD 2022)